# Retrieving firebase storage url synchronously?

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage

I have an list of object having list of file names like this:

```
Object 1
    Files
     file1:1234
     file2:2345
Object 2
     Files
     file1:456
     file2:656
```

I am iterating over each object and inside each object I am iterating over each file and query firebase storage for getting url of each file , in order to display it to a datatable as a hyperlink.

```
var tableData = [];
//Code to Loop over the objects
  var myApp ={ fileurls:[]};
  var i =0;
  angular.forEach(filesContainer.filenames, function(value, key) {
            storageRef.child('/myfiles/'+ value)
            .getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                myApp.fileurls[i] = url;
                i++;
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                });
  });
tableData.push();
//Loop over object ends here
//invoke successcallbackfunction to display the tableData
successcallbackfunction(tableData);
```

The problem with my above code is that due to asycnhronous firebase calls ,`myApp` array is always empty. How can I ensure that  the line `tableData.push()` get executed only when looping over the files of an object is complete?

Comment: One thing, do you need to update your javascript code by changing  var myApp ={ fileurls[]};  to var myApp = { fileurls: [] };   ?

Comment: was a typo while pasting the code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
angular.forEach(filesContainer.filenames, function(value, key) {
            storageRef.child('/myfiles/'+ value)
            .getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                myApp.fileurls[i] = url;
                i++;
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                });
```

to:

```
angular.forEach(filesContainer.filenames, function(value, key) {
            storageRef.child('/myfiles/'+ value)
            .getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                myApp.fileurls[i] = url;
                i++;
                  if (i == filesContainer.filenames.length) {
                       tableData.push();
                       //Loop over object ends here
                       //invoke successcallbackfunction to display the tableData
                       successcallbackfunction(tableData);
                  }

                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                });
```

So once the last iteration is complete, then execute your desired code.

Comment: that logically incorrect , I need to make the success callback after the object loop ends not the file loop . My loop over object is essentially a forEach on firebase query snapshot

Answer (score 0):

The [`Reference.getDownloadUrl()` function returns a `Promise`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL). So that means you can do the usual promise gathering with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
var tableData = [];
var i =0;
var promises = [];

angular.forEach(filesContainer.filenames, function(value, key) {
    promises.push(
        storageRef.child('/myfiles/'+ value).getDownloadURL()
    });
});
Promise.all(promises).then(functions(urls) {
    var myApp ={ fileurls: urls };
    tableData.push();
    successcallbackfunction(tableData);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error");
});
```